Does the time until $k$th photon arrival follow a Gamma distribution?
Assuming that photons in every macroscopic light source have Poisson statistics, it should follow that the waiting time until the $k$th photon has been emitted has a Gamma distribution, right?
From (DeGroot, Schervish):

"For a Poisson process with rate $β$, the times between successive occurrences have the exponential distribution with parameter β, and they are independent. The waiting time until the kth occurrence has the gamma distribution with parameters k and β."

I am modeling the behavior of a pixel that uses an integrate-and-fire architecture (it is basically a form of pulse-frequency modulation). The parasitic capacitance of the photodiode is discharged at a rate given by its photocurrent, and after Vph passes a certain threshold Vref, the output of the comparator switches and self-resets the photodiode.

I wanted to make a simple model that ignores all the noise sources of the circuit and photodetection, and only consider the arrival of photons. In a way, one could argue that the comparator switches on the k-th arrived photon. And therefore, the Tisi would follow a Gamma distribution, because it is the waiting time until the k-th photon in a Poisson Process.
Do you think this logic is, ultimately simple, but correct?
